# Upgrade needed dialogbox for my application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, auto-update

Hi GUys
In our company we have some specific softwares that have several releases during a year and we were wondering to notify the clients about new releases automatically. How can we code this functionality? I mean from where should we begin? we have an ftp which will contain those files. And How is that possible for us just to do the upgrade without uninstall and re-installing the whole package?

Any relevant help is appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=application+update+patch+c%23

Answer (score 1):

Checkout NAppUpdate:

http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/

http://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate (Licensed under the Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

## Application Updater Component

This component is written in the .NET Framework and enables you to make your application auto-updatable simply by dropping the component into your existing .NET applications and setting a few properties (ex. where to get updates from).

You can download it [here](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx).